# How to reverse geocode without Google?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, geocoding

I have a basic tracking system i've written with OpenLayers using google and openstreetmap and I want to use geocoding to get street names etc

However, I'm a bit confused.
I was hoping there was a easy/free way with OL and OSM however, i'm not sure there is

I've tried using Google, but it doesn't work with bulk data.
It allows me to get about 3 or 4 back and then doesn't work for the rest..... i think they require a wait period between each request

Can anyone recommend a free way to geocode without Google?
please be patient with my lack on knowledge in this areas

Comment: Do you need *reverse* geocoding where you obtain a street address from lat/lon, or do you need regular bulk geocoding where you obtain lat/lon from a street address?

Comment: If the question is about geocoding, please make that clear in the title (and check out the *very closely* related thread at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18818/whats-the-easiest-way-to-do-a-one-time-mass-geocode-580-000-addresses).

Comment: I need to reverse GeoCode - i.e. give lat/long and get physical address

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest [gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com) that you can install it locally and do the number of request you want without any limitation, the data are from geonames and openstreetmap. so it is totally free as you need. you can also add /edit/ remove data via a GUI. (those kind of things you can not do with google ;)

Comment: Although your user name is suggestive (and obviously you're not trying to hide anything there!), whenever you recommend a solution with which you are commercially associated, please make that connection clear in your reply.

Comment: Thanks your website looks good, for the sake of the forum, its free right (if hosted myself)?

Comment: the forum is free to post message but can not be hosted in an other website (if i understand the question)

Comment: sorry I meant for the sake of other people looking, can you clarify if gisgraphy is free to use and you can host it on your own server to do the data lookup locally for Reverse GeoCoding

Comment: ok, i understand :) gisgraphy is free and so does the free services but the free services are for testing purpose or occasional use only. If you plan to use it for commercial use or make a lot of requests, you have to install it, everything is free and you can have strictly the same functionnalities.I also have some premium services (installation dump or hosted service).