# Get coordinates from address

Tags: javascript, geocoding, coordinates, php, address

I am writing a application which allow users to save a address into database (db) and in the next step it shows all addresses on a map. But in the saving step I need automatically calculate a GPS coordinates and save them into db too. But I don't know how calculate them because I don't want to show map in saving step so I can't use a Google Maps API.

```
Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; 
geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.
```

Is there a similar service without the restriction?

Comment: which country are you operating in? or is it world wide?

Comment: I need at least central europe, but it should be world wide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to do a one-time mass geocode? (580,000 addresses)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18818/whats-the-easiest-way-to-do-a-one-time-mass-geocode-580-000-addresses)

Comment: @R.K. It is similar, but I need get only one geocode per request. And solutions don't fit because probably are limited only for United States  (they can't parse my addresses)

Answer (score 1):

ESRI's geoservice's are also simular to google's.

For example fetching a json result for Antwerp: 
http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=antwerp&f=pjson

And they also support multiple languages.

More info on:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-online-geocoding-rest-api/index.html#/Overview_of_the_World_Geocoding_Service/02q000000008000000/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://www.geonames.org/ ?
It has some webservices can return coordinates

Comment: I checked them but I didn't find any suitable webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Mapquest provides an [open api](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/geocoding-service) with the same interface as their licenced api.  You could also try [nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) directly.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but I am afraid that almost every solution are made only for some countries and are not suitable for using world wide. I tried almost ten different web services but only google api is universal.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the Google Maps Geocoding API restriction is that the resulting points must be displayed on a Google Map; it doesn't say they must be displayed immediately. That is, you may store the geocoded coordinates in your database and display them at a later time as long as it's on a Google Map. Here's the [pertinent](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12) text (**emphasis** mine):

> (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not
>   pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, **except that you may store: (i)
>   limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the
>   performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily**
>   (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a
>   manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service;
>   and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs
>   Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must
>   not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or
>   other local listings information.